# Manipulando valores através do input hidden

Tags: php

Fiz uma calculadora da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['calcularbtn'])) {

    $valor1 = $_POST['valor1'];
    $valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
    $tipo   = $_POST['tipo'];

    if ($tipo == 'Somar') {

        $operador  = '+';
        $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;

    } elseif ($tipo == 'Subtrair') {

        $operador  = '-';
        $resultado = $valor1 - $valor2;

    } elseif ($tipo == 'Multiplicar') {

        $operador  = '*';
        $resultado = $valor1 * $valor2;

    } elseif ($tipo == 'Dividir') {

        $operador  = '/';
        $resultado = $valor1 / $valor2;

    } elseif ($tipo == 'Potência') {

        $resultado = pow($valor1, $valor2);

    } else {

        $resultado = pow($valor1, 1 / 2);
    }

    echo $resultado;
} else {
    echo "Esperando cálculo...";
}
?>
```

Ela funciona, mas agora a dificuldade é guardar todas as contas e fazer algo como um histórico para fazer a exibição. Tentei com session, mas sem sucesso:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['calcularbtn'])) {
    $_SESSION['historico'] = array(
        'valor1' => $_POST['valor1'],
        'valor2' => $_POST['valor2']
    );

    echo $_SESSION['historico']['valor1'] . " $operador " . $_SESSION['historico']['valor2'] . " = " . $resultado;
} else {
    echo "Sem operações realizadas...";
}

?>
```

Comment: O que está faltando? Qual a saida?

Comment: Está faltando o histórico, cada cálculo que eu fazer precisa aparecer a conta na mesma página, tipo a calculadora do windows 10 e 8.Vou editar com a imagem da calculadora.

Comment: Mas qual a saida do que foi feito ate agora?

Comment: A sáida é o resultado da operação com o " echo $resultado " e a conta feita com " echo $_SESSION['historico']['valor1'] ." $operador ". $_SESSION['historico']['valor2'] ." = ". $resultado ; "

Comment: A ideia é de que, toda vez que eu aperte no botão para calcular ele mostre o resultado da conta e vá adicionando da página todos as contas feitas sem apagar a primeira conta feita.

Comment: Você pode criar um arquivo history.txt

Comment: E o que eu faço nesse arquivo ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry da uma olhada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente eu armazeno o histórico em um input oculto(hidden).

A ideia consiste em enviar ao seu script php o valor atualizado do campo o histórico em uma variável post. Assim que ela chega no seu script é concatenada com a string que representa a operação atual.

Bem, inicialmente ela está vazia mas após a primeira execução ela passa a acumular o histórico contido no input:

```
 $historico = $_POST['historico'] . '</br>' . $valor1 . $operador . $valor2 . '=' . $resultado ;
```

Assim o valor dentro do input vais sendo atualizado:

```
<input hidden="" type="text" name="historico" value="<?php if (isset($historico)) { echo $historico; } ?>" >
```

Adicionei somente esse bloco dentro do seu if:

```
 if(isset($valor2) && isset($valor1) && isset($operador)){
            $historico = $_POST['historico'] . '</br>' . $valor1 . $operador . $valor2 . '=' . $resultado ;           
            echo $historico;
            echo "</br>";

        }
```

Ele verifica se as variáveis das operações estão setadas e adiciona a variável `$histórico` o valor do input oculto:

```
<input hidden="" type="text" name="historico" value="<?php if (isset($historico)) { echo $historico; } ?>" >
```

Esse campo tem a função de enviar ao seu script php o histórico a ser concatenado com `'</br>' . $valor1 . $operador . $valor2 . '=' . $resultado ;`

Observe que eu uso isset para não haver alertas de variáveis vazias quando não estiverem setadas.

**Código completo**

```
<?php  

if ( isset($_POST['calcularbtn']) ) {
    
        $valor1 = $_POST['valor1'];
        $valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    
        if ($tipo == 'Somar') {
    
            $operador = '+';
            $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;
    
            }elseif ($tipo == 'Subtrair') {
    
            $operador = '-';
            $resultado = $valor1 - $valor2;
    
            }elseif ($tipo == 'Multiplicar') {
    
            $operador = '*';
            $resultado = $valor1 * $valor2;
    
            }elseif ($tipo == 'Dividir') {
    
            $operador = '/';
            $resultado = $valor1 / $valor2;
    
            }elseif ($tipo == 'Potência') {
    
            $resultado = pow($valor1, $valor2);
    
            }else{
            $resultado = pow($valor1, 1/2);
    
            }
                echo 'Resultado=' .  $resultado;   
            }else{
               echo "Esperando cálculo...";
            }        
         if(isset($valor2) && isset($valor1) && isset($operador)){
           $historico = $_POST['historico'] . '</br>' . $valor1 . $operador . $valor2 . '=' . $resultado ;
       }
    
    ?>
    
    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input hidden="" type="text" name="historico" value="<?php if (isset($historico)) { echo $historico; } ?>" >
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="valor1"  size="5" placeholder="Valor 1"><br>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" name="tipo" >
                <option selected="selected">Somar</option>
                <option>Subtrair</option>
                <option>Multiplicar</option>
                <option>Dividir</option>
                <option>Potência</option>
                <option>Raiz Quadrada</option>
            </select><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="valor2"  size="5" placeholder="Valor 2"><br>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="calcularbtn" value="Calcular">
    </form>`

<?php

    if(isset($historico)){          
          echo $historico;
          echo "</br>";
                   
        }
    
    ?>
```

**Conclusão**: Existem um bilhão de maneiras de se fazer isso. Porém existem formas mais adequadas. Essa não é a forma mais adequada de se construir uma calculadora utilizando php assim como construir isso usando php não é adequado.
Porém para fins didáticos a utilização de campos ocultos são bastantes úteis para trafegar dados do cliente para o servidor sem que o usuário tenha controle sobre eles.

**Dica:**
Use `javascript` com ele você pode deixar o processo dinâmico e utilizar mais recursos. Pense: para que perguntar pro servidor algo que seu navegador já sabe ?.
Pergunte ao browser sobre javascript e ele saberá muito bem o que fazer com seus dados. Além é claro, de não ter que ficar recarregando a mesma página para obter o resultado.

Comment: Pode explicar o que está acontecendo aqui ?

Comment: Adicionei informações à resposta. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O problema é que o script php, não pode ficar acima do form pois os resultados das operações e o histórico aparecem abaixo do form.E se eu colocar esse script que vc fez a baixo do form ele dá erro.

Comment: É só ecoar histórico abaixo do form. Veja a edição

Comment: E por que ele da erro caso eu usar o echo abaixo ?

Comment: Percebi que você colocou um "#" no action do form, Qual a necessidade disso ?

Comment: Bem eu estou executado o script na mesma página: action="#" . Espero que você tenha colocado todo esse código em um único arquivo.  cal.php  .. você só precisa de um arquivo nesse caso. Copie todo o código para ele e veja funcionando.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76383/discussion-between-atila-silva-and-lone-tonberry).

Answer (score 2):

O código tem vários erros, veja:

Você está verificando a variável `$_POST["calcularbtn"]`, não seria `$_SESSION["historico"]`?

```
if (isset($_SESSION["historico"]))
```

Você está sobrescrevendo o valor da variável, o certo seria utilizar o `array_push`, ou seu shorthand:

```
$_SESSION["historico"][] = array(/* criação de novo elemento aqui */)
```

Você está utilizando o operador e o resultado que acabou de salvar. O ideal seria salvar eles junto aos valores na variável de sessão:

```
$_SESSION["historico"][] = [
        'valor1' => $_POST['valor1'], 
        'valor2' => $_POST['valor2'],
        'operador' => $operador,
        'resultado' => $resultado
    ];
```

Você está imprimindo só o que acabou de ser salvo, lembre-se que a variável `$_SESSION["historico"]` é um array de arrays, então você deve iterar de alguma forma sobre seus elementos:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["historico"] as $key => $value ){
    echo "{$value["valor1"]} {$value["operador"]} {$value["valor2"]} = {$value["resultado"]}\n";
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Eg6JS7).

Comment: Está dando erro nesse echo. Warning: Illegal string offset 'valor1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\atividades\calculadora.php on line 116

Comment: @LoneTonberry Pode me mostrar como o seu código ficou?

Comment: Agradeço sua ajuda, mas o Atila também resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

### Com session seria assim:

**PHP**

```
session_start();                   

if ( isset($_POST['calcularbtn']) ) {

    $valor1 = $_POST['valor1'];
    $valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

    if($tipo  == '+'){
       $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;
    }else if ($tipo == '-'){
       $resultado = $valor1 - $valor2;
    }else if($tipo == '*'){
       $resultado = $valor1*$valor2;
    }else if($tipo == '/'){
       $resultado = $valor1/$valor2;
    }else if($tipo == 'pow'){
       $resultado = pow($valor1, $valor2);
    }else{
       $resultado = pow($valor1, 1 / 2);
    }
    //resultado da operação
    echo "<span style='color:red'>".$resultado."</span>";
    echo "<br>";

    //armazenando valores no array 
    $_SESSION['historico'][] = $valor1.",".$tipo.",".$valor2.",".$resultado;

    //imprime a session para simples verificação podendo ser retirada do código
    print_r($_SESSION['historico']);

    echo "<ul>";

    //itera para apresentação do historico
    foreach($_SESSION['historico'] as $list){

        $parte = explode(",", $list);

        if ($parte[1]=="pow" && $parte[3]!="1/2") {
            echo "<li>".$parte[0]."<sup>2</sup>=".$parte[3]."</li>";
        }else if($parte[1]=="1/2"){
            echo "<li>".$parte[0]."<sup>1/2</sup>=".$parte[3]."</li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li>".$parte[0].$parte[1].$parte[2]."=".$parte[3]."</li>";
        }
    }

     echo "</ul>";

}else{
    echo "Esperando cálculo...";
}
```

**HTML** repare que os options contém `value`

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="">
<div class="form-label-group">
   <input class="form-control" type="number" name="valor1" size="5" placeholder="Valor 1"><br>
   <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" name="tipo" >
       <option selected="selected" value="+">Somar</option>
       <option value="-">Subtrair</option>
       <option value="*">Multiplicar</option>
       <option value="/">Dividir</option>
       <option value="pow">Potência</option>
       <option value="1/2">Raiz Quadrada</option>
   </select><br><br>
</div>
<div class="form-label-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" name="valor2" size="5" placeholder="Valor 2"><br>
</div>
  <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="calcularbtn" value="Calcular">
</form>
```